# R: How to create a png from summary

Tags: r, png

I have some data on which I created some plots but I'd also like to create a png with the output of summary:

```
summary(latency$delta)

 Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 

0.01180  0.02875  0.03747  1.02900  0.06670 35.13000
```

I haven't found how to do that. Is it possible?

2. Is it possible to make summary output also the 95 percentile?

Comment: For (2), try `quantile(latency$delta, probs=c(0,0.05,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.95,1))`.

Comment: You need to tell us what graphics system you prefer. Or do some searching on `tableGrob` .... or just use `text` if base graphics will suit the task.

Answer (score 2):

```
test <- summary(mtcars$mpg)
# test is now essentially a named numeric vector
png(): plot(NA,NA, xlab="", ylab="",ylim=c(0,1), xlim=c(0,1), axes=FALSE)
# Need to blank out the axis labels and axes and box
text(0.5,0.5, paste(names(test), collapse="   " ))
text(0.5,0.45, paste(test, collapse="     " ))
dev.off()
```

If you wanted to add a couple of more spaces the alignment might improve. The grid based tableGrob approach would take care of that for you.

[image]